# How to invoke a remote program in Java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to invoke an exe on a remote computer, supposing we know the absolute path of the exe where it lies?

I have written a client and a server program and am able to get both work as expected when both are running. But now, all I want to do is to invoke the server program from client if server is not running. Seems like defeating the purpose of server-client model but still.

If that is possible without knowing the login credentials of the remote system, then it'd be cool. Eg: There are softwares like 'PsExec' that need login credentials.

I understand that, such a feature may not be there, as it would mean a serious security threat, but, I am just wondering if there is some sort of a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If that is possible without knowing
>   the login credentials of the remote
>   system, then it'd be cool. Eg: There
>   are softwares like 'PsExec' that need
>   login credentials.
>
> I understand that, such a feature may
>   not be there, as it would mean a
>   serious security threat, but, I am
>   just wondering if there is some sort
>   of a workaround.

Those "inconvenient" security rules are there for a purpose.  You simply **do not** want people to be able to run any old program on your machine without proper authentication and authorization.  Not even if you are behind a firewall.

Why?

In one word - Viruses!  If some machine on your network gets infected with a virus (or similar malware), then all machines that run a non-authenticated remote execute service would be at serious risk of infection.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gridserver](http://www.datasynapse.com/gridcomputing) technologies... it's based on grid technology and very efficient and easily deployable.

Comment: I can't figure out how that is related to the question. Please clarify.

Comment: Grid Technology solves this sort of problems and let's your run java and other type of binaries remotely. "is it possible to invoke an exe on a remote computer, supposing we know the absolute path of the exe where it lies?"

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a messaging system like a remote procedure call, webservice, or simple tcp socket on the server to do a wake up on the server process.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can execute an exe is by executing a local application which you have access to. There **must** be a part of the software running on the computer you want to execute an application on. From there, you can do a remote call from a second program on a remote machine asking the local one to do his job : execute.

As stephen C said, it would be a violent breach of security if I could run exe on your machine without your permision.

Comment: "violent breach of security" - the violence would probably come later :-)